# Can i create apple or android application using c?

Tags: c

I was wondering if i can create an application using C because android applications nowadays are programed using java and i don't have a lot of knowledge in Java programing

Comment: C, C++, and C# are three different languages, none of which are Java. Pick a *single* language and ask a *specific* question, because this post is far too broad currently.

Comment: Not that I know any, but I am peferclty sure that there are hundres of c complilers for the apple os,

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called the NDK to create statically linked libraries that Android can call. Remember these are linked libraries (.so files) and so they do not have a Main in the traditional sense. To find more information on that follow this link. http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

It's important to note that you will still need to write some Java code but it allows you to do a lot of the non GUI work via C code.

On the flip side IOS programs are written in Objective-C which sounds similar to C but from what I've been told it's very far apart.

Comment: BTW, Apple is a company, not a product, and so can't be "written." :)

Comment: Haha oops my bad there fixed that.